# Why will the acquireQueued be called after tryAcquire failed in In AbstractQueuedSynchronizer?

Tags: java.util.concurrent

I cannot understand the meaning of this design.

When tryAccquire method  is called,and it will return false when the lock is held by another thread, why not just addWaiter to sync queue and park this thread,waiting to be invoked?

In accquireQueued method ,the first thread node waiting is get out to tryAcquire again.I guess it will fail to acquire the lock very likely.

```
public final void acquire(int arg) {
    if (!tryAcquire(arg) &&
            acquireQueued(addWaiter(Node.EXCLUSIVE), arg))
        selfInterrupt();
}
final boolean acquireQueued(final Node node, int arg) {
    boolean failed = true;
    try {
        boolean interrupted = false;
        for (;;) {
            final Node p = node.predecessor();
            if (p == head && tryAcquire(arg)) {
                setHead(node);
                p.next = null; // help GC
                failed = false;
                return interrupted;
            }
            if (shouldParkAfterFailedAcquire(p, node) &&
                    parkAndCheckInterrupt())
                interrupted = true;
        }
    } finally {
        if (failed)
            cancelAcquire(node);
    }
}
```